# Exit code checking of WinSCP script

Tags: batch-file, private-key, public-key, winscp, errorlevel

I need to securely transmit files to a server using WinSCP as a function in a batch script.

I need WinSCP to use a `.ppk` file, I already have on the machine to authenticate instead of a password.

Once connected I need to upload files via WinSCP to the server.

If there are any issues/errors while running WinSCP, I need its exit code to be sent back to the script. The idea is; if there is any issues with transmission to show the exit code. I will write an `if` statement that if the exit code is anything other than zero to quit the program.

Any assistance on how to implement WinSCP into a script with exit code checking would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is a .NET API for WinSCP. You can learn more about it at:
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library

You just need to write a little code to get your job done. Here is an example:
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library#example

To see more browse any of the example of your choice at:
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_examples

Answer (score 0):

See the official example for [checking WinSCP script results](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation#results).

```
winscp.com /ini=nul /log=example.log /script=example.txt
if %ERRORLEVEL% equ 0 (
  echo Success
) else (
  echo Error!
)
```